# Range.setStartAfter() in Chrome does not work correctly with spans or inline elements

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a content editable div.
I have some text that looks like this:

```
adsadsd <span>asdsa </span>  moretextasdasd
```

I am trying to use Range.setStartAfter() to set the caret to the right of a span tag. This works correctly in IE and in firefox, but does not in chrome. In Chrome the caret is at the end of the span tag, instead of after it.
setStartBefore() works in all browsers.

It works in Chrome if it's a DIV element, but not a span element.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vXnCM/5234/

Notice if you click focus then start typing, you will be inside the span and not outside of it as you will be on IE and firefox.

Does anyone have an explanation or a work around for Chrome?

update: it appears inline elements are broken in chrome for this. Using a div, but setting display:inline-block makes the same behavior happen

Comment: BTW for anyone in the future, I submitted a bug about this to chromium and they verified. So far (a year later) it has not been fixed. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=586964#c3

Comment: Over two years and still no fix =(

Comment: Over 4 years and still no fix ! :'(

Comment: Now 5 years later and guess what...

Comment: And now 6 years later and not fixed. smh

Comment: Now that execCommand is deprecated, opting to ignore this bug is going to cause problems in the future. Let's see what happens in another several years.

Comment: still the same in 24

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is inconsistent in chrome.

I have solved it adding a dummy suffix node (space) at the end and then calling `setStartAfter` on the inserted suffix node. There may be a better way, but this seems to work as of now.

```
   var sel = window.getSelection();
   var range = document.createRange();
   var suffixNode;

   range.setEndAfter(specialTagContainer);
   range.collapse(false);

   range.insertNode((suffixNode = document.createTextNode(' ')));

   range.setStartAfter(suffixNode);

   sel.removeAllRanges();
   sel.addRange(range);
```

If adding space is not the behaviour you would want, then you can just create a empty `TextNode`.

Comment: I know it's been a few years but what was the purpose of assigning the node to the suffixNode within the insertNode function argument?

Answer (score 0):

just put `$('#two')[0].contentEditable = false;` at first line of your code and it works! ;)

After set caret position, you can set contentEditable to true again.

Comment: This does not work. Can you share actual working code ?